# Keeping track of static method calls in a class using java.util.Observer

Tags: design-patterns, static-methods, observer-pattern

I'm a beginner programmer, and am wondering how to work around this issue. The problem I am trying to solve is keeping a tally of static method calls in my program using a java.util.Observer.

Clearly, my original post must have just confused people so I'll leave it more open-ended: can anyone suggest a way to keep a static method count on a class that extends Observable?

Thanks for looking

Comment: Community wiki questions are better suited for questions that don't have a definite answer or are subjective.  A better way to solicit responses (if you had some reputation to spare -- not an option for you yet) would be to offer a question bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response. It was helpful. I solved this by adding a static method to my class which extended Observer, so that it has two update methods:

```
public static void update(Method method)
{
    //update count here
}

@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object obj) {
            //override code to handle observable's call to update

    }
```

Whenever I ran into a static method that I needed to keep a count of, I called `MyClass.update()` and passed a reference to the calling Method using Reflection API's `getEnclosingMethod()`.

ex:

```
MyObserver.update(new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod());
```

Seems to work ok.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods don't change state of objects.  Classes that extend Observable use Observable to notify Observers of changes to state.  It doesn't make sense to me to have a static method call `hasChanged` or `notifyObservers`, because it shouldn't have changed anything. The Observer's `update` method gets called with a reference to the changed object and a static method isn't associated with any instance of a class, so the whole idea doesn't make sense.

The `Observable` object calls the observer something like this (this isn't really the code):

```
notifyObservers(){
    for(Observer observer : observers){
       observer.update(this, null);
    }
}
```

Calling notifyObservers from a static method doesn't make sense.  `this` has no meaning here.

Change your method to non-static if it must fit into this scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Observer object's update method is stand alone, you can do anything.